# How I can get rid of border around image?

Tags: html, css

I can't find a source of problem. I want get rid of border around image.

Problem:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xeFmt

Solution should be cross browser with support of IE8+.

Comment: `img { border: 0; }`?

Comment: @putvande That's what I thought, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well the border will disappear as soon as you put a src to your img.

Comment: That codepen is useless without an image source in it.

Comment: @RomainBraun I have never seen this before, is it possible to remove the border without adding a src?

Comment: I don't presume that src is mandatory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

w3 says [SRC is mandatory.](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html)

> SRC (Source)
>   The SRC attribute specifies the URI for the image to be embedded. Its syntax is the same as that of the HREF attribute of the  tag. SRC is mandatory.

Adding any value to the src (even a missing image) makes the border/outline disappear, without having to modify the css.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eaJum

Answer (score 1):

Normally it would be:

```
  outline: none;
  border: none;
```

I suspect CodePen may be adding that so you can see the element or until you add a real src to the tag.

Comment: I tried that as well. Neither CodePen, JSFiddle, or my own test server will work while trying to find an answer to this problem.

Comment: I write src attribute and paste image url, but I see the ill-fated border(

Answer (score 0):

Normally it can be achieved by

```
border: none;
outline: 0;
```

But not for the case when actual image is missing, i.e. not loaded or src attribute is not specified

Comment: That isn't an answer then. The poster is asking how to remove the border without specifying src.

Comment: there was an answer - it's impossible, as browser intentionally renders the border when image is missing

Answer (score 0):

As Romain Braun suggested, adding source to the `<img/>` tag will remove the border.

```
<img src="http://9to5google.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/google2.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an image src="" attribute to it should remove the border but I would also add a `border: none;` to the CSS.